# Special FUT Cards with 99 stats

Tags: fifa-18

[image]

This player usually has a 66 (see [here](http://www.futhead.com/18/players/20527/julian-riedel/)). According to some googling it's a special card for real pro players.

Does this actually mean whenever I see such a card I play against that very same guy that's on it or are there other ways to encounter them?